# Getting com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list. on adding places sdk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-places-api, dex

I started facing this error when I added the new google places sdk to my app. This is the full stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: xyz[removed name]/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0, 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.android.volley.ParseError
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.android.volley.ParseError
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
    ... 10 more
```

These are the imports (only including the relevant ones, the full list is big)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

I also have multidex enabled set to true. I tried, `clean`, `Inavlidate Caches/Restart`, restarting Studio. Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!!

Edit: Adding full dependency block

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    // Facebook SDK Core only (Analytics)
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.33.0'
    // Facebook Login only
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.14.2'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    /**
     * Google
     */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    //compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.2.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    // CardView
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.multiviewpager:library:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.1@aar'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
    /*For Request Server*/
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.1.6.0'
    /**
     * Animation.
     */
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    implementation 'net.soulwolf.widget:ratiolayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    /**
     * Event Bus.
     */
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
    /**
     * Ring capcha
     */
    implementation 'com.thrivecom:ringcaptcha:1.0.11@aar'
    /**
     * Zendesk
     */
    implementation 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.7.1'
    implementation 'com.zendesk:support:2.0.0'
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'
    implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    // Room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    // Paging
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'
    // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'
    // Test helpers for Room
    testImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.shuhart.bubblepagerindicator:bubblepagerindicator:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
    implementation 'co.omise:omise-android:2.6.4'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.13.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.19'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation project(':menu')
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    //OTP
    implementation 'com.poovam:pin-edittext-field:1.1.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:data-collector:2.22.0'

    //Applozic
    implementation 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:5.33'
    //Places SDK
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Post your full dependencies block

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Program type already present: com.android.volley.ParseError
```

This error generally means you have two dependencies that are both providing the same class, causing a conflict.

You could run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to list down all dependencies of all the libraries that you have included in your project. With this you can figure out the libraries that have common dependencies.

Comment: BTW **'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18' is deprecated**. You would want to use **'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'** which is the official google Volley

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: One more observation. Looks like volley and retrofit are part of this project. Both are network libraries for similar purposes. You could have one of them and remove the other. This would help you reduce the size of your APK by a bit.

Comment: I understand. It is actually a big and an old project and multiple people worked on this, I started working on it recently

Comment: Btw this error started on adding the palces sdk dependency so that must be the culprit, how do I resolve this if I know that.

Comment: If you are sure that places sdk has some reference to volley, then you may exclude volley by using _implementation "places" {exclude group: 'com.mcxiaoke.volley'}_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194820/discussion-between-dinesh-and-varunkr).

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your Places SDK to the new version, follow this migration guide: [Migrating to the New Places SDK Client](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration).
In there is says that when *adding*:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

One should *remove*:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

That should also be the case with 16.1.0.